# Error when launching a basic application (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I'm trying to run a basic application (Basic Activity) on Android Studio 2.2.2, but when I launch it on a Nexus 5 emulator it gives me this error:

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x40000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\/system.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\/system.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\Dylan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\/system.img': Invalid argument
```

I have checked into this folder and system.img is here.

After some time I have this error:

> Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_24_2 was killed.

I choosed API 15 (Android 4.0.3 IceCreamSandwich) and the emulator on Android 7.0.

Someone said me that it doesn't work because the path to the disk image is too long but it seems weird.